# Sublime Text 2 - Auto complete issues

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimecodeintel

I just recently swapped out Espresso with Sublime Text 2 because of the large amount of available packages. I use the software mainly for web developing and installed quite a few packages.

All Autocomplete, AndyPHP, PHP Completions KIT and SublimeCodeIntel for completions.

The reason for installing all these, and not just SublimeCodeIntel is because SublimeCodeIntel did not work as I expected.

None of these(together or not) will complete classes, functions or variables names defined in project files.

Just an example to illustrate the problem.

If I define a simple function in one of my files,

```
function sayOutLoud($x) { echo $x; }
```

and when I start typing sayOu... I would like Sublime to suggest the function name, and if I choose sayOutLoud I want to know what arguments the function takes(of course I know, but you  understand). Should not anyone of these packages do this?

update: after a reboot, strangely enough some completion started working. But it doesn`t give me the argument list.

If I disable SublimeCodeIntel(the package I was told to be one of the best), nothing changes, so in other words, it does not add anything when its active.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest you to do this by creating you own snippet if you're using this function a frequently,  here is a simple snippet that you can use (you don't need any sublime plugin )
1) go to  **tools > new snippet**   the default content of the page that you will get is something
   like this :

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

2) write your function definition in the third line (remove Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.)

in our case the function definition will be like this :

```
function sayOutLoud(${1:\$x}) { ${2:echo} ${3:\$x};${4:} }
```

3) **uncomment** the sixth line so it would work if you type the sayOutLoud (replace the sixth line with the following)  an you press **tab**:

```
<tabTrigger>sayOutLoud</tabTrigger>
```

4) save the file under the name **sayOutLoud.sublime-snippet**

NOW If you open any php file and you type sayOutLoud you will see an auto completion 
and if you press **tab**  you will see the function added to you file and that's IT.